# How long was G1 Optimus dead?

Tags: tv, transformers

In the G1 continuity, Unicron attacks the Earth and Cybertron in the year 2005, and during a battle with Megatron, Optimus dies.

Of course, Optimus is revived in later episodes of the tv show. The first time he is "revived" is in the episode *[Dark Awakening](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Dark_Awakening_%28episode%29)* (S03E08). Hot Rod briefly discusses how long Optimus has been dead.

> **Hot Rod**: Come on guys, he's just shook up a little. You'd be too, if you'd been dead for years.

It had always been my understanding that Season 3 of the G1 cartoon took place very soon after the movie. Daniel's age does not appear to change between the movie and the episodes of season 3.

How many years had Optimus been dead by this point? Alternatively, how many years took place between the end of *Transformers: The Movie* and Season 3 of the TV show?

Comment: Of course, in the UK comic continuity, he *stayed dead*.

Comment: Poor Rodimus. It's not enough that he's tainted as the guy who let Megatron kill Optimus, he gets upstaged by him too only a few months later.

Comment: @SystemDown Well, it's his own fault for being such a crappy Autobot.

Comment: *Very* NSFW: [The Rude Awakening of Optimus Prime](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bq1_6D9QS9Y&feature=kp)

Comment: @phantom42 - Auto *brat*.

Comment: I laughed out loud when he renamed Kup...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the bottom of the that particular page that you linked for [Dark Awakening](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Dark_Awakening_%28episode%29) the whole being dead for years is stated to be a [Continuity Error](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Dark_Awakening_%28episode%29#Continuity_errors).

If we take into account Daniel being the same age as when Prime died, then it should only have been a few months... In Japan the continuity seems to be a little better considering the revival takes place in 2010.

> Shortly after Optimus Prime first awakens, Rodimus Prime states that
>   Optimus has been dead "for years". Unless he means dog years, this is
>   impossible, considering season 3 starts immediately after the 1986
>   movie. Also, Daniel is the same age he was when Optimus died. In
>   actuality, Optimus probably hasn't been dead more than a few months.
>   This works a little better in Japan, though, where the series takes
>   place in 2010.